# Laying out a React component, where should margins go?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, styled-components

I am having some issues on understanding the best way to style a react component and layout its position.

Where should the margins / padding go for laying out the component that resides inside another component?

Coming from my bem knowledge, a component should never lay itself out, otherwise it can't effectively be reused. The parent component should be in charge of laying out its child components.

I am quite new to React, so what is the best way of doing this?

If I pass styles down into the component then that would mean that the child would be in charge of laying out itself.

Or I can pass in a style tag?

Would this be valid?

I am coming from a sass background but I am wanting to either use styled components or styles within JavaScript. I am not looking to import sass, so I am quite flexible and open to ideas.

Comment: your knowledge from before applies here as well. there's nothing special about react in this case. you can always pass style down, or have a default style and be able to override that style, or use classnames. you may want to look at https://emotion.sh/ since it does everything styled-components does and more which allows for more flexibility

Comment: Hi Martin. You may not be aware, but on Stack Overflow, the community prefers a technical writing style, for both questions and answers. We therefore discourage chatty material, and [volunteer editors](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors) will often remove it. Thanks, help-appreciated, please-help, hope-its-clear, etc are all trimmed. A quick search indicates you have rather a lot of these, which is storing up quite a lot of extra work for editors - could you make your posts a bit more succinct?